# Creating a namespace in ASP.NET project VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, epplus

I'm trying to use the EPPlus package in a ASP.NET (VB.NET) project and having trouble converting the code from C# to VB and getting the error "'ToDataTable' is not a member of 'OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage'. I put the namespace file in the App_Code folder is that the right place?

.aspx.vb page:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If FileUpload1.HasFile Then

        If Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName) = ".xlsx" Then
            Dim package As ExcelPackage = New ExcelPackage(FileUpload1.FileContent)
            GridView1.DataSource = package.ToDataTable()
            GridView1.DataBind()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

.aspx page where I reference the EPPlus_Import namespace

```
<%@ Page Title="PCA Complaints" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" 
CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="EPPlus_Code" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="EPPlus_Import" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
<asp:FileUpload ID="fileUpload1" runat="server" CssClass="btn-primary btn-sm" />

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
CssClass="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered table-condensed GridView">
</asp:GridView>
```

I put this file in App_Code folder and not sure it belongs there.

```
Imports OfficeOpenXml
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Namespace EPPlus_Import

Module ExcelPackageExtensions
    <Extension()>
    Function ToDataTable(ByVal package As ExcelPackage) As DataTable
        Dim workSheet As ExcelWorksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.First()
        Dim table As DataTable = New DataTable()

        For Each firstRowCell In workSheet.Cells(1, 1, 1, workSheet.Dimension.[End].Column)
            table.Columns.Add(firstRowCell.Text)
        Next

        For rowNumber = 2 To workSheet.Dimension.[End].Row
            Dim row = workSheet.Cells(rowNumber, 1, rowNumber, workSheet.Dimension.[End].Column)
            Dim newRow = table.NewRow()

            For Each cell In row
                newRow(cell.Start.Column - 1) = cell.Text
            Next

            table.Rows.Add(newRow)
        Next

        Return table
    End Function
End Module
End Namespace
```

Comment: have you installed nuget package related to excel package? https://www.nuget.org/packages/OfficeOpenXml.Core.ExcelPackage

Comment: seems like .ToDataTable() is an extension method check your c# code some where there is an extension method created, you may need to migrate that bit of code to resolve this method issue.

Comment: Yes, I installed this nuget.org/packages/OfficeOpenXml.Core.ExcelPackage and version 5.4.1 of EPPlus using nuget manager.  There is an extension method called ToDataTable, which I have defined in a class called ExcelPackageExtenstions but it doesn't seem to be working. I created a file called ExcelPackageExtenstions.vb and put it in the App_Code folder. Not sure this is right

Comment: please update the signature of your extension method?